# Fill in missing data from Queryset Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I've inherited a AngularJS / Django application using DjangoRestFramework and a Postgres DB which is being re-platformed from AngularJS to React / Redux.
One of the things we're trying to do is present time series data using amCharts4. A problem (among many others) we're having is presenting data over a time range for which there may be no entries in the DB. For example, we have results which might look something like:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        "result": 3
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "result": 2
    }
]
```

And would like them to look something like:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        "result": 3
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "result": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "result": 2
    }
]
```

Additionally, we also have data with multiple data points per time event:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-01-13T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-14T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "No"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "No"
    }
]
```

And would like the data filled in with 0's for any `name` on any date where there isn't a result:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-01-13T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-13T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 0,
        "name": "No"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-14T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 0,
        "name": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-14T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "No"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-15T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 0,
        "name": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-15T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 0,
        "name": "No"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 0,
        "name": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00Z",
        "result": 1,
        "name": "No"
    }
]
```

The range of these results is also not necessarily governed by the start and end dates in the date but may be specified by the user. In this case, we would need to fill in zero value results for all options for all dates in those ranges.

I'm aware of amCharts `skipEmptyPeriods` property ([amCharts4 - skipEmptyPeriods](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Removing_empty_time_units)), but my frontend engineers have told me this won't work for the cases of multiple trend lines (i.e., the second case where there are multiple options per date). Also, this isn't really a frontend problem and will cause performance issues down the line.

Additionally I've tried using Postgresql's `generate_series` function with `coalesce` [Postgresql - generate_series](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/03/14/fun-with-sql-generate-sql/) but wasn't able to get this to work for the second case.

Currently I'm trying this in Pandas (which I've never used) and have a solution to the first problem of single entries per date but, again, and having trouble with the second case of multiple entries per date:

```
    from_date = request.query_params.get("from_date")
    to_date = request.query_params.get("to_date")

    # let's do some zero plotting
    filtered_queryset = list(filtered_queryset)
    if from_date:
        from_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y-%m-%d").astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    else:
        from_date = filtered_queryset[0]["date"]
    if to_date:
        to_date = datetime.strptime(to_date, "%Y-%m-%d").astimezone(pytz.UTC)
        _now = localtime(now()).astimezone(pytz.UTC)
        to_date = min(to_date, _now)
    else:
        to_date = localtime(now()).astimezone(pytz.UTC)

    pandas_freq_map = {"day": "D", "week": "W-MON", "month": "MS"}
    freq = pandas_freq_map.get(request.query_params.get("frequency"))

    idx = pd.date_range(from_date.date(), to_date.date(), freq=freq)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(filtered_queryset))
    datetime_series = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
    datetime_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(datetime_series.values)

    df = df.set_index(datetime_index)
    df.drop("date", axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = df.asfreq(freq)
    df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    df_json = json.JSONDecoder().decode(df.to_json(date_format="iso"))

    # this (result or 0) tomfoolery is bc I don't understand why pandas sometimes reindexes with null as the fill_value
    prepared_response = [{"date": date, "result": (result or 0)} for date, result in df_json["result"].items()]
```

Comment: If you're working with time series data, are you using something similar to [TimeScale](https://www.timescale.com/)?  This seems it would need a specialized solution, and Pandas may very well be the best interim solution.

Comment: @Jason unfortunately I don't have the time, or approval from the product team, for any system changes. Yet.

Comment: Seems to me you could use this as an indicator of further problems down the line if you're not given the time to implement the necessary specialized changes.  IMO, using pandas for this is a hack that really shouldn't be taken as a good solution.

Comment: Totally agree and will definitely add this to my arsenal of evidence that we need to make some changes. Did find a solution though using Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued with the Postgres solution and did find a working query:

```
WITH
unnested_select AS (
    SELECT unnest(forms_completedformfield.value_text_array) as unnested_array,
           date_trunc('day', created) as created
    FROM forms_completedformfield
    WHERE forms_completedformfield.completed_survey_id =
        ANY(
            ARRAY['815251ac-3891-4206-b876-d17898b74e66'::uuid, '74aea6f5-9860-4fe5-8820-68a279726c83'::uuid, '173ea91f-0dc8-4a6c-b330-7c3cee13e1b4'::uuid]
        )
    GROUP BY unnested_array,
             created
),

range_counts AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', unnested_select.created) as date,
           count(unnested_select.unnested_array) as ct,
           unnested_select.unnested_array as ar
    FROM unnested_select
    WHERE unnested_select.unnested_array =
        ANY(
            ARRAY['2b0076f1-7be5-4e52-9879-47e4eeafe175']
        ) 
    GROUP BY unnested_select.unnested_array,
             unnested_select.created
),

range_sums AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', unnested_select.created) as date,
           count(unnested_select.unnested_array) as ct
    FROM unnested_select
    GROUP BY unnested_select.created
),

range_values AS ( 
    SELECT date_trunc('day', min(created)) as minval,
           date_trunc('day', max(created)) as maxval
    FROM unnested_select
),

frequency_range AS (
    SELECT generate_series(minval, maxval, '1 day'::interval) as date
    FROM range_values
),

field_options AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT unnested_select.unnested_array as ar,
        frequency_range.date
    FROM unnested_select
    CROSS JOIN frequency_range
)

SELECT  
        frequency_range.date as fd,
        field_options.ar as far,
        range_counts.ar as rar,
        range_counts.ct as ct
FROM frequency_range
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_options ON frequency_range.date = field_options.date
LEFT OUTER JOIN range_counts ON frequency_range.date = range_counts.date and field_options.ar = range_counts.ar
ORDER BY 
        frequency_range.date
```

Obviously the hard coded values in the `ARRAY`s will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an attempt to create a solution with panda. Basically you can resample and then reindex with the date range, but this becomes a bit clunky with the composite index

Setting up the data

```
import pandas as pd
data = [    { "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00.000Z", "result": 3 }, 
            { "date": "2020-01-18T00:00:00.000Z", "result": 2 }, 
            { "date": "2020-01-13T00:00:00Z", "result": 1, "name": "Yes" }, 
            { "date": "2020-01-14T00:00:00Z", "result": 1, "name": "No" }, 
            { "date": "2020-01-16T00:00:00Z", "result": 1, "name": "No" }]

# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data )
df.name = df.name.fillna("No")
df.date = pd.to_datetime( df.date)
```

Then process the data

```
# set up date range
idx = pd.date_range( df.date.min() , df.date.max() , freq="H")

# resample yes/no for name separately
df = df.set_index(["name", "date"]).sort_index()

no = df.loc["No"].resample( rule="60min").sum().reset_index()
no["Name"] = ["No"] * len(no)
no.set_index( ["Name", "date"], inplace=True)

yes = df.loc["Yes"].resample( rule="60min").sum().reset_index()
yes["Name"] = ["Yes"] * len(yes)
yes.set_index( ["Name", "date"], inplace=True)

# reindex with the full date range
yes = yes.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["Yes"]*len(idx), idx], names=('Name', 'date')), fill_value=0)
no = no.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["No"]*len(idx), idx], names=('Name', 'date')), fill_value=0)

# merge and create output (dateformat has to be adjusted)
df = pd.concat( [yes, no], axis=0)
df.reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Result

```
[{'Name': 'Yes',
  'date': Timestamp('2020-01-13 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  'result': 1},
 {'Name': 'Yes',
  'date': Timestamp('2020-01-13 01:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  'result': 0}, ....
]
```